# replace text between domain name and html file link

Tags: php

http://somting.com/replace-this/free-downloads-somting-full-version.html

i want to replace anything between 2 slashes "/replace-this/" with single "/"

with php script

i get page url with php

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
```

Comment: Sure - what's your budget? If you want us to do all the work, you don't expect it to be free, right?

Comment: i just need the one line script which remove text "/replace-this/"

Comment: But seeing as you haven't done any effort to solve the problem yourself, your task might be better suited for a site such as freelancer.com where you can pay people to solve your problem. When you post questions to StackOverflow we require you to do an actual effort yourself - we're not your code monkeys.

Comment: like $url = str_replace("/"*."/","rapidfiles.us",$url);

Comment: You look like you're trying to do something regex could be good for. `preg_replace` can help you out.

Comment: what is the conman latter used in php for many different combinations as (.*) in htaccess

Comment: `.*` is regex. `~/.*/~` is the regex you want to replace. I'll let you figure the rest yourself - it's not that hard.